# How to fix this error in Laravel when creating a category

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, laravel-5.5

I am creating a website for a blog. I have added a category page quickly updated, but not returned to the index: category.php,CategoriesController.php. I'm using Laravel v5.5 and OpenServer.

**Category.php**

```php
namespace App;

use Cviebrock\EloquentSluggable\Sluggable;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Category extends Model
{
    protected $fillable = ['title', 'slug',];

    public function user()
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany(
            User::class,
            'id_idcat',
            'gid',
            'idcat'
        );
    }

    public function sluggable()
    {
        return [
            'slug' => [
                'source' => 'title'
            ]
        ];
    }
}
```

**CategoriesController.php**

```php
namespace App\Http\Controllers\Admin;

use App\Category;
use App\Http\Controllers\Controller;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use View;

class CategoriesController extends Controller
{
    public function index()
    {
        $categories = Category::all();

        return view('admin.categories.index', ['categories' => $categories]);
    }

    public function create()
    {
        return view('admin.categories.create');
    }

    public function store(Request $request)
    {
        $this->validate($request, [
            'title' => 'required' //обязательно
        ]);

        Category::create($request->all());

        return redirect()->route('admin.categories.index');
    }
}
```

**create.blade.php**

```php
{!! Form::open(['route' => 'categories.store']) !!}
<div class="box-header with-border">
    <h3 class="box-title">Добавляем категорию</h3>
</div>
<div class="box-body">
    <div class="col-md-6">
        <div class="form-group">
            <label for="exampleInputEmail1">Название</label>
            <input type="text" class="form-control" idcat="exampleInputEmail1" name="cat">
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
<!-- /.box-body -->
<div class="box-footer">
    <button class="btn btn-default">Назад</button>
    <button class="btn btn-success pull-right">Добавить</button>
</div>
<!-- /.box-footer-->
{!! Form::close() !!}
```

I can not find a mistake. I did similar tasks several times.

Answer (score 0):

Your Data isn't validating as there is no input named title because it's named cat, so your validator is redirecting you back with errors, but your blade isn't showing errors so you don't see them.

Change Name of the field in your create view and add errors as below:

Edit: also add CSRF to form

create.blade.php

```
@if ($errors->any())
    <div class="alert alert-danger" role="alert">
        @foreach ($errors->all() as $input_error)
            {{ $input_error }}
        @endforeach
    </div>
@endif

    {!! Form::open(['route' => 'categories.store']) !!}  
    {{ csrf_field() }}
    <div class="box-header with-border">
        <h3 class="box-title">Добавляем категорию</h3>
      </div>
      <div class="box-body">
        <div class="col-md-6">
          <div class="form-group">
            <label for="exampleInputEmail1">Название</label>
            <input type="text" class="form-control" idcat="exampleInputEmail1" placeholder="" name="title">
          </div>
      </div>
    </div>
      <!-- /.box-body -->
      <div class="box-footer">
        <button class="btn btn-default">Назад</button>
        <button class="btn btn-success pull-right">Добавить</button>
      </div>
      <!-- /.box-footer-->
      {!! Form::close() !!}
```